# Recreating max-width in outlook as well as emulate a viewport tag

Tags: html, email, templates, responsive-design, outlook

I need to create a an email template in outlook, and I've made one that works great in all email clients but outlook. From what I've read, it's because max-width and the vieport meta tag don't work in outlook. I have trying out some hacks to get my code to look right in outlook but to no avail. Here is my rough layout:

```
<table width = "100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:20px;height:20px;" height="20">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width = "800px">
    <table id="container" height:"100%" width:"100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto; background-color:#ebebeb">
    </table>
  </td>
  </td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

I was told this would emulate max-width. A table with width-100%, a tr with three td elements, and the middle element containing a table with all my content. However it's not working.

What can I do to emulate max-width and viewport in outlook and make my email responsive? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To cover **ALL** email clients, including desktop Outlook and mobile Gmail, **you need a hybrid/spongy approach**:

```
<div style="max-width: 800px;">
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="800"><tr><td>
  <![endif]-->
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 800px;">
    /* email code */
  </table>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    </td></tr></table>
  <![endif]-->
</div>
```

At its core, it uses max-width and min-width to impose rigid baselines (allowing some movement) and imposes a fixed, wide width for Outlook who is shackled to desktop anyway (since Outlook doesn't support max-width and min-width). Once a mobile-friendly baseline is set, media queries progressively enhance the email further in clients that support it.

It's pretty verbose and essentially requires two sets of markup (one for desktop Outlook and one for everyone else), but this approach will get you total coverage in the major email clients, including Windows desktop Outlook.

[This template](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/blob/master/cerberus-fluid.html) shows a basic version of this code in action.